# Fullscreen bootstrap card with highcharts (100% height)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, fullscreen

I have several (bootstrap) cards where I would like to have the opportunity to show this fullscreen. Highcharts charts are present in these cards. The problem is that the height of the highcharts does not adapt when you are going in full screen mode.

A while ago I asked the same question with bootstrap panels and then "daniel_s" made [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jx46s9gn/) example for panels. Only now I have added a number of columns at the bottom and it has been converted from panels to cards. Unfortunately the example is not working anymore.

Is there a possibility to automatically adjust the scaling of the highcharts so that the ratio (columns at the bottom and header) remains the same as in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/8pe2zhk5/1/) example?

In addition, I would also like to know how I get the header the text and icons on one line. So that the text is on the left and the icons are on the right.

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var charts = [];
  var chart1Info = {
    containerId: 'container',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };
  var chart2Info = {
    containerId: 'container2',
    definition: {
      title: {
        text: 'Chart2 Title'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          label: {
            connectorAllowed: false
          },
          pointStart: 2010
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
      }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
      }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
      }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
      }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
      }]
    }
  };

  function drawChart(chartInfo) {
    // Properties that vary by chart should be defined in chartInfo
    // Any properties that are the same for all charts are added here 
    chartInfo.responsive = {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    };

    if (chartInfo == chart1Info) {
      charts[0] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    } else {
      charts[1] = Highcharts.chart(chartInfo.containerId, chartInfo.definition);
    }

  }
  //Toggle fullscreen
  $(".fullscreen-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('i')
      .toggleClass('fa-expand')
      .toggleClass('fa-arrows-alt');
    console.log($(this).closest('.card'))
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('panel-fullscreen');
    var chartInfo = $this.attr("id") === 'panel-fullscreen' ? chart1Info : chart2Info;
    console.log($this.id, chartInfo);
    drawChart(chartInfo);
  });

  drawChart(chart1Info);
  drawChart(chart2Info);



  // Export buttons
  $('#png').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart();
  });

  $('#jpeg').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'jpeg',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#pdf').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'pdf',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#svg').click(function() {
    charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'SVG',
      filename: 'my-svg'
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('csv').onclick = () => {
    charts[0].downloadCSV()
  };

  document.getElementById('xls').onclick = () => {
    charts[0].downloadXLS()
  }

  $('#print').click(function() {
    charts[0].print();
  });


  $('#png2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart();
  });

  $('#jpeg2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'jpeg',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#pdf2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'pdf',
      filename: 'my-pdf'
    });
  });

  $('#svg2').click(function() {
    charts[1].exportChart({
      type: 'SVG',
      filename: 'my-svg'
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('csv2').onclick = () => {
    charts[1].downloadCSV()
  };

  document.getElementById('xls2').onclick = () => {
    charts[1].downloadXLS()
  }

  $('#print2').click(function() {
    charts[1].print();
  });
});
```

```css
.panel-actions {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.panel-actions a {
  color: #333;
}

.panel-fullscreen {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.card_border {
  border: solid 0.75px #fa7921;
}

.card_border2 {
  border: solid 2px #fa7921;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card with-margin card_shadow card_border rounded">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row border-bottom-0 card_border2" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #fa7921);">
            <h3>Panel title
              <ul class="list-inline panel-actions float-right">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen" class="fullscreen-btn" role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a></li>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="fas fa-list-ul"></span></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="print">Print</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="png">Download PNG</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="jpeg">Download JPEG</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="pdf">Download PDF</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="svg">Download SVG</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="csv">Download CSV</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="xls">Download XLS</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body border-top-0 border-bottom-0 card_border2">
              <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white justify-content-center card_border">
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Saves
              <p class="h4">1700000</p>
              <p class="text-danger margin h6">-2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card with-margin card_shadow card_border rounded">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row border-bottom-0 card_border2" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #fa7921);">
            <h3>Panel title
              <ul class="list-inline panel-actions float-right">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen2" class="fullscreen-btn" role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a></li>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="fas fa-list-ul"></span></button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="print2">Print</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="png2">Download PNG</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="jpeg2">Download JPEG</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="pdf2">Download PDF</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="svg2">Download SVG</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="csv2">Download CSV</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="xls2">Download XLS</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body border-top-0 border-bottom-0 card_border2">
              <div id="container2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-white justify-content-center card_border">
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Saves
              <p class="h4">1700000</p>
              <p class="text-danger margin h6">-2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center card_border2">
              <br> Likes
              <h4>1700000</h4>
              <p class="text-success margin">2.1%</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the easier one question, namely that one:

> In addition, I would also like to know how I get the header the text and icons on one line. So that the text is on the left and the icons are on the right.

Your floating is not working because the flex container is not supporting `float` property, so in order to position it as you want, please set the `justify-content: space-between` on parent element.

Regarding the issue with height, please try to set `chart.height: '100%'` in your chart configuration object, and let me know it solved the problem.

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row border-bottom-0 card_border2" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #eea849, #fa7921); justify-content: space-between">
            <h3>Panel title</h3>
            <ul class="list-inline panel-actions">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" id="panel-fullscreen" class="fullscreen-btn" role="button" title="Toggle fullscreen"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></a></li>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="fas fa-list-ul"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="print">Print</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="png">Download PNG</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="jpeg">Download JPEG</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="pdf">Download PDF</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="svg">Download SVG</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider dropdown-item"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="csv">Download CSV</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" id="xls">Download XLS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>

            </div>
       </div>
```

Chart config:

```
var chart1Info = {
containerId: 'container',
definition: {
    chart: {
     height: '100%'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
  }, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
  }]
 }
};
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hnLr14o5/

[EDIT]

After conversation in comments below, you need to set the both containers `height` attribute value equal to `100%`, then delete this property from your charts configurations. Also, please delete the `style="height: 220px"` attribute from both `.card-body` elements, and instead of that - define a new class called (for example) `.row-200` which sets the `height` to `200px`, and assign it initially to this two elements.

Finally you can toggle created class on your button click event by this line of code:

```
$($(this).parents()[3]).find('.card-body').toggleClass('row-200')
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/kdv3sy85/

Kind regards!

Comment: Thanks for the first part of the question! For the second part of the question I have forgotten to add that I would like the container to be 220px high. That is why I added the following section to bootstrap container: style = "height: 220px;" At highcharts I have done the following addition: height: 200. In full screen mode, I still want the entire screen is filled without scroll option. Hopefully this is possible. This is the new [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/uvLpnrb0/3/)

Comment: I've editted the answer above. Please refer to it, and if it's what you want, mark as the answer to your question.

Comment: I copied your example to codepen.io so you can see it in fullscreen mode. You have made two examples. In the first example the fullscreen works excellent [EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/Lodewijk/full/oMEMXm/). The second example works almost perfectly [EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/Lodewijk/full/mjXjdN/). Unfortunately, the container is not 100% filled as in the first example. Do you know what adjustment needs to be made to get this working? Thanks again for all the effort you have made so far.

Comment: It's happening because Codpen's `<header>` fixed position what is not respected if you set `height 100%` on some element, so if your app also has the fixed menu, then you just need to set the height for a bit less than 100% or use fixed height for both elements in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thanks again daniel_s. I have tried several variants this weekend but unfortunately no solution was found. I also do not understand what exactly you mean by header because in both examples the header of codepen.io is present? Maybe a lot to ask but you would really help me if you could make an example. Hopefully you have time to make this. Thanks again for the effort you have made so far

Comment: Please try to run your app on some `localhost` server, without codepen platform, just your app. Then it should work as you expecting.